# What level of performance should I expect from RavenDB?

Tags: ravendb

I've been looking for a good NoSQL database for some of our projects for quite some time and I recently discovered RavenDB which looks pretty awesome from a .NET support perspective, so I decided to try it out and write a little benchmark. First order of business was testing insert speed, using the following code:

```
class Program
{
    private const int TEST_COUNT = 10000;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        var store = new DocumentStore();
        store.Url = "http://localhost:8117";
        store.Initialize();

        var timer = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        var session = store.OpenSession();
        for (var i = 0; i < TEST_COUNT; i++)
        {
            session.Store(new TestEntity()
            {
                Name = "Test Entity"
            });

            if (i % 127 == 0)
            {
                session.SaveChanges();
                session.Dispose();
                session = store.OpenSession();
            }
        }

        session.SaveChanges();
        session.Dispose();
        timer.Stop();

        Console.WriteLine("Processed {0:n0} records", TEST_COUNT);
        Console.WriteLine("Time elapsed: {0:n0} ms", timer.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        Console.WriteLine("Records / sec: {0:n0}", TEST_COUNT / (timer.ElapsedMilliseconds / 1000d));
    }
}

class TestEntity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }

    public TestEntity()
    {
        Created = DateTime.UtcNow;
    }
}
```

The output is as follows:

```
Processed 10,000 records
Time elapsed: 9,531 ms
Records / sec: 1,049
Press any key to continue . . .
```

This is on a relatively fast machine (3ghz, 2gb ram running Windows 7)

Call me crazy, but 1000 inserts / sec is horribly slow, especially for documents that contain a mere two fields. Is this to be expected? I know RavenDB is optimized for reads, not writes, but this is pretty bad.

Comment: Did you allow for a warm up period, such that JIT and other startup activities were factored out?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't know if you're going to get much faster than that due to the whole "optimised for reads, not write" thing.

But if you read through [this thread](http://groups.google.com/group/ravendb/browse_thread/thread/fa2dde8697013440) there are some suggestions:

- Batch up writes (which you are doing). I'm not sure you need to close and then re-open the session though, you should just be able to call `SaveChanges()`
- Set the transaction mode to lazy (`Raven/TransactionMode`)
- Do the imports asynchronously, i.e from several threads

One other thing you could try is the `embedded mode`, i.e change your session to

```
var documentStore = new DocumentStore { DataDirectory = "path/to/database/directory" };
documentStore.Initialize();
```

This bypasses the HTTP traffic and inserts documents directly, see [the docs](http://ravendb.net/documentation/docs-client-api-index) for more info.

Comment: I did try all of these and the performance gain wasn't noticable. I guess RavenDB is just too slow for my usage scenarios (write heavy). I'll give you the answer anyway, but the issue is kind of unresolvable at this point.

Comment: You might want to post this on the RavenDB mailing list http://groups.google.com/group/ravendb/. I'm far from a RavenDB expert so you might get a better answer.

Comment: There was some performance tuning done for write heavy scenarios earlier in 2011.  You would probably get better results now.